# How many pistons are used in Excavator Engine and how they coupled with pumps?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, hydraulics

As I am examining the components of a Caterpillar 323D hydraulic excavator, I would like to inquire about the specifics of its diesel engine. Can you provide information on the number of pistons and strokes in the engine? Additionally, could you explain how the engine is connected to the multiple pumps?

Comment: Rexroth have pumps that are designed to bolt together.

Comment: What are the first 3 digits of the serial number?

Answer (score 2):

The Caterpillar 323D hydraulic excavator is powered by a Cat C7.1 ACERT engine. The engine specifications are as follows:

- Engine Model: Cat C7.1 ACERT (Inline 6-cylinder)
- Net Power (ISO 9249): 149 hp (110 kW)
- Displacement: 7.1 L
- Maximum Torque (SAE J1995): 502 lb-ft (681 Nm) at 1500 rpm
- Emissions: EPA Tier 2 / EU Stage II equivalent

The hydraulic system in the Caterpillar 323D uses two main variable-displacement axial piston pumps, along with one gear pump for the pilot system. These pumps provide hydraulic fluid flow for the machine's operation, including the boom, stick, bucket, swing, and travel functions.

The hydraulic pumps are mechanically coupled to the engine using a damper flex plate. The damper flex plate acts as a flexible coupling that connects the engine output shaft to the hydraulic pump input shaft. It absorbs torsional vibrations and shock loads, allowing for smoother operation and reducing wear on the hydraulic pump and engine components.

### Source

Caterpillar Performance Handbook, Edition 46

Comment: How does single engine is connected to 2 pumps in the excavator?

Comment: @Prerna they are usually bolted.

Comment: The pumps are stacked and bolted together and share the same shaft

Answer (score 1):

This is a great course to follow if you are interested in the subject of hydraulic power.

https://www.coursera.org/lecture/fluid-power/hydraulics-and-pneumatics-SD8dv

Do you have a specific engine in mind? Most diesel engines are 4 stroke, if you have a specific engine in mind you will be able to know how many pistons it has. If you are looking for a suitable engine then you will find it it depends on the required loads, If I were to guess I would say that you have multiple pumps on a single axle that are coupled to an engine. The hydraulic controls determine the amount of torque or load transmitted to the engine.

I hope that helps.

Comment: yeah I want to know how many pistons are used in Cat  323D excavator engine ?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the Cat website? It seems like this is the engine, which is an in-line 6. https://www.cat.com/en_GB/products/new/power-systems/industrial/industrial-diesel-engines/18279748.html#:~:text=Boasting%20one%20of%20Caterpillar%27s%20most%20modular%20engine%20designs,wide%20variety%20of%20machines%E2%80%94especially%20industrial%20and%20construction%20applications.