# How does the hydraulic valve system work in excavators?

Tags: automotive-engineering, hydraulics, valves

There are many types of valves used in excavators. Two are important: the main valve and the pilot valve. Is the pilot valve is controlled by the operator and the main valve is controlled by the pilot valve? But I can't imagine this system properly. How can the pilot valve control the main valve? Additionally, I am not able to understand the flow of oil after pumping. Will it go to the main valve or the pilot valve?

Comment: How did you get on with the course suggested here? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/54548/10902

Comment: I asked the question here to get the accurate answer in a few lines. I dont want any course or book link.

Comment: I gave you that simple answer as the first line in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the pilot valve as a "lever" to control the main valve.

If you obtain a system diagram then you can follow what happens.

There are many texts available that describe the functions of all the parts in a hydraulic system. I have the set of Hydraulic books by Mannesman Rexroth Sigma, now part of Bosch, so I don't know if they still produce them. Worth searching for and reading.

This is a link to one of the series (they were produced in several languages, in fact they also produced a technical dictionary across 6 languages which I still find useful):
[enter link description here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/374504887248?hash=item57323b13d0:g:SeQAAOSwKcNiwzyE&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8KOeTJxwjJW7Ryx%2BIF4euJOCboZrL8ZnAzu4LzmEa%2BHM4cqD3Qv%2FXlwWkQm%2BDECsyMjQe8RHbommq%2FBTjRLjxrAYLyPi9ZnNfBj9EdCo3wBCnHR1M%2FVjzEGnSFsP2ck5x6labwajnkcfkuJbDI5SKSieKoiaPxp5h2pEwgnx6kihSjZvXZeCwDJwf%2F1a4ZsKSu4%2BXv5%2Bz8vCNKOUxjbbAI%2BAMgtt%2Fj3HD5rMgJhmuRYUIajSf4UkpQMLXhokpMheMfVUNk3ibRr6ksBnSlkehpwH9FWvAvcZuu1M4aPp2M%2BTqfPtM9NZgS9th8VLU0rQww%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR_bNwLHgYQ)